# Chapman-Kolmogorov equations

Tags: stochastic-processes

The stochastic process $\{X(t), t \geq 0\}$ is called homogeneous and will have stationary jump probability if $$P_{ij}(s, t)=P(x(t)=j \mid x(s)=i))=P_{ij}(0, t-s), \forall t, s \geq 0$$

We write $P_{ij}(t-s)$ for the probabilities $P_{ij}(s, t)$.

The Chapman-Kolmogorov equations are written as $$P_{ij}(t+s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P_{kj}(t)P_{kj}(s), \forall t, s \geq 0$$

Can you explain to me why at the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations we have a formula for $P_{ij}(t+s)$ and before we had $P_{ij}(t-s)$ ???

Why does it stand that at the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations at $P_{kj}(t)$ the index is $kj$ and not $ik$ ???

Comment: Seems like a typo. Also, what is $m$?

Comment: So you mean that $P_{ij}(t+s)$ is a typo and it should be $P_{ij}(t-s)$ ??? $m$ shouldn't exist... It is a typo... @Math1000

Comment: Oh, I meant that it should be $ik$ and not $kj$ in the first term in the sum.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Do you maybe have also an idea for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151298/the-chain-jumps-from-the-situation-i-to-j @Math1000 ???